# Как установить python пакет в WHL формате без использования pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

python3-pip пакет тянет в зависимостях gcc и прочее. Пакеты уже скомпиленны и их нужно просто установить.

Пакет wheel теперь не имеет команды install

Comment: «python3-pip пакет тянет в зависимостях gcc и прочее» — это неправда, у pip нет никаких обязательных зависимостей кроме собственно питона.

Comment: уже поправил, не заметили что оно в рекомендациях.  оставить вопрос или удалить?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-wheel
```

Comment: `python3-wheel` используется только для сборки новых пакетов и на самом деле тоже не очень нужен

Comment: Для установки колес не требуется?